# How do i store a textview using Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

So my question might have been asked many times but i couldnt find an answer anywhere on the internet to it .

. What i want to do is store a textview using sharedprefeences .

In my first class (xp) i,m sending the textview to another class (feedback)
Now the feedback is reciving the textview with no single problem , but never saves it. How can i store that textview in the (feedback) class even after closing the app ??

Here's the class which is intenting the textview

```
public class Xp extends Activity {
Button accept;
TextView textV;
TextView xbnum;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xp);
    accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept);
    textV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
    xbnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xpnum);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value1 = extras.getString("intent_xp");
        final String value = extras.getString("intent_extra");
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
        edit.putString(PREFS_NAME, value);
        edit.putString(PREFS_NAME,value1);

        textV.setText(value);
        xbnum.setText(value1);


        edit.commit();
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Xp.this, feedback.class);
                i.putExtra("intent_extra", textV.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }
}

}
```

And here is the class which will recive the intent and save the textview (As supposed )

```
public class feedback extends Activity {
TextView test1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feedback);
    test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("intent_extra");
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("intent_pref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
        edit.putString("intent_pref",value);
        test1.setText(value);
        edit.apply();

    }

}

}
```

The class is reciving the text , and everything is okay . Only when i close the app and open it , everything is cleared out ..

Comment: If I understand you correctly you probably need use *general* shared preferences instead of activity-specific preferences.

Comment: Why are you using different SharedPreference names? What else does your feedback activity do besides save a value? Do you ever retrieve values from SavedPreferences?

Comment: I named the sharedprefrences the same name and still not saving . For now i only want it to save that value and show it there , later i,m gonna be adding more function .

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm wrong but it seems that you missunderstood how shared preferences works.

If you want to store several values in a preferences file an access it in others classes you have to create one instance of a SharedPreferences.

In your case it means create in both "feedback" and "Xp" a SharedPreferences instance like this :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", SharedPreferences.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and then use this instance to store your datas with an editor.
Be careful if you can't store several value for the same key.

You can also store your value in several files as you are actually doing. But if you want to set your textview with the value of your preferences file you have to get it with the `getString("key_of_your_value")` method on your shared preferences instance.

Comment: I,m sorry i tried everything you said and still didnt work . i created that instance in both classes , used the same name in both classes . Didnt work . I even tried the `settings.getString` and still didnt work . I mean it shows but never saves . Any other suggestion please ?